# pgfplots : duplicate y-axis label

Tags: pgfplots

I would like to a plot a line graph. The coordinates y are values from 0 to 0.035.

However, the y label ticks are completely wrong, with duplicate values, e.g. there are two '0.03' labels. The plot is of course wrong as well due to this.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=0.9\textwidth,compat=newest}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[
axis lines = left,
xlabel = Instance,
ylabel = {Average Deviation (\%)},
scaled y ticks=false, 
y tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed, /pgf/number format/precision=2},
symbolic x coords={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11},
xtick=data,
xticklabels={$10\times5EG$,$10\times5EH$,$10\times5FH$,$12\times3EG$,$12\times3EH$,$12\times3FG$,$12\times3FH$,$12\times4EG$,$12\times4EH$,$12\times4FG$,$12\times5EG$},
]
\addplot
[
color=red,
mark=square
]
coordinates{(1,0.019)(2,0.029)(3,0.000)(4,0.015)(5,0.003)(6,0.000)(7,0.000)(8,0.035)(9,0.000)(10,0.012)(11,0.004)};
\legend{MBBOTS algorithm}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Few points here.

1. You won't need

   ```
    symbolic x coords={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11},
    xtick=data
   ```
2. Increase precision in `/pgf/number format/precision=5`. Now since you use low precision `0.015` and `0.02` are shown same.
3. You have long xtick labels. So rotating them will be a good idea.

With all these we have:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=0.9\textwidth,compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[
axis lines = left,
xlabel = Instance,
ylabel = {Average Deviation (\%)},
scaled y ticks=false,
y tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed, /pgf/number format/precision=5},
%symbolic x coords={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11},
%xtick=data,
x tick label style= {rotate=45,anchor=north east},
xticklabels={$10\times5EG$,$10\times5EH$,$10\times5FH$,$12\times3EG$,$12\times3EH$,$12\times3FG$,$12\times3FH$,$12\times4EG$,$12\times4EH$,$12\times4FG$,$12\times5EG$},
]
\addplot
[
color=red,
mark=square
]
coordinates{(1,0.019)(2,0.029)(3,0.000)(4,0.015)(5,0.003)(6,0.000)(7,0.000)(8,0.035)(9,0.000)(10,0.012)(11,0.004)};
\legend{MBBOTS algorithm}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works perfectly. Really appreciate your help. Gratitude.

Comment: this diagram is put inside my thesis. for the width, i use 0.9\textwidth. What do you think is the suitable height?